# ios action extension does not show up in chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, ios8, ios8-extension

I was wondering, how do I get my ios8 safari extension to be picked up by Chrome in iOS.

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2014/09/chrome-for-ios-adds-supports-for-extensions/

Does it just have to be on the app store? or is there something specific that I need to do.

Apparently if I use Javascript that blocks out any possibility of adding it as a action extension for Chrome

Comment: Does the extension work with Safari on iOS?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes sir

Comment: I am facing the same problem with my app. Working fine with safari but not able to get response from 3rd party browser. Let me know if you got answer.

Comment: @ShashankKulshrestha that's not how it works apparently

Comment: @Hades :Did u get the solution of above problem, How did u fix this?